# How do I set "display:none" after 5 seconds to the div i previously set "display:initial" in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, function

I'm trying to create a greeting pop-up and make it appear for only 5 secs, but I don't really get how to make it work.

Thanks in advance!

Here's code:

```
function greeting(event){
  if (time >= 6 && time <= 11 ){
    goodMorning.style = 'display:initial'
  } else if (time >= 13 && time <= 17){
    goodDay.style = 'display:initial'
  } else if (time >= 17 && time <= 22) {
    goodEvening.style = 'display:initial'
  } else {
    welcome.style = 'display:initial'
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

No need for all that complicated work. Just use a `setTimeout` to execute a function after a specified number of miliseconds.

```js
var goodEvening = document.getElementById("a");
setTimeout(function(){hide(goodEvening);}, 5000);
function hide(element){
  element.style.display="none";
}
```

```html
<p id="a">Good evening!</p>
```

jQuery approach:

```js
setTimeout(function(){$('#a').hide();},5000);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="a">Good evening!</p>
```